# adding infinites fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using working to build my app and I have come to a situation here.

I have a `fragment` "product" with the name and price of the product so, when the user clicks on "buys" or sells" he will see a list of `fragments`.

I would like to add as `fragments` as products has the DB but all I have seen is that I need a `<FrameLayout>` per `fragment`. Is there a way I can do this dynamically from the code?

Thank you,
Alvaro.

Comment: please elaborate. it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: try to implement listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes you can add fragment dynamically with code.
2. Are you sure that Fragments are what you want ? The way I uderstand what you are saying, I think that you need to show a list of Views.

   A View is something which will show informations and can listen for user inputs (like touch input). It's pretty simple to manage.

   A Fragment is something way more complex which can contain a view but is much more powerful and heavy (both in term of performance and in term of code complexity). Quite usually a Fragment will represent the whole screen of an application.

So take a look at Views and at what they can do, then take a look at ListViews to see how you can dynamically take data from your database and print it with it.